# Implement FilePicker to OpenCart Product page

Tags: upload, opencart, filepicker

Has anyone tried to implement the FilePicker Upload module to a OpenCart product page?

I am using OpenCart version 2.xx

Comment: Frontend or backend ?

Comment: on the front end, I would like to let my client upload their picture using Filepicker Instead of using the preloaded one. I know they have one for Wordpress.